# Persistent http sessions (browser/instance restart ) in GAE - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I was wondering if there was a "standard" way for handling persitent HTTP sessions in a GAE based web app. Let me explain my issues.

If I only use this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession() to get a session, this session will be automatically invalidated once the user closes the browser.

If I go with Cookies (so the session will persist until the cookie expires or the user erases his cookies), I need to have a kind of mechanism for validating that the sessionID stored in the cookie actually belongs to a valid session. I've thought about storing a key value pair of sessionID, HttpSession in a concurrentHashMap, but now I run into the problem that this hashmap will be available only for the current instance, therefore I might run into consistency problems.

The last solution I thought of was keeping track of the session in the datastore, but it seems pretty ridiculous to me having to query the datastore each time I receive a request.

Maybe I'm totally out of the track and there's a really simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do: Http sessions that persist across browser restarts and multiple gae instances.

Thanks!
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically use a cookie to implement remember-me. The idea is to generate a random and unique cookie for an authenticated user, store it with the rest of the user information in the database, and send the cookie to the client browser.

Now, when the client comes back 5 days later, the cookie is sent with its first request to your application. At this time, if the user is not authenticated yet, you can extract the cookie from the request, find the user in the database who owns this cookie, and automatically authenticate him as if he sent his credentials.

This solution doesn't need to modify anything to how the sessions are handled by GAE.

Comment: So I should use a combination of both, session and cookies, first check if a session is available, if not I should look for the cookie? Now sessions are valid only for the scope of a servlet right? What if another instance of a jvm is turned on? Would'nt that make the sessions inconsistent? Available in one servlet and not in the other

Comment: A session is typically created the first time one is asked for, and doesn't have anything to do with the fact that the user is authenticated or not. It's used to store attributes for several subsequent requests. For example, as soon as a JSP is executed, you have a session. Once a user is authenticated, you remember it by  storing some flag or user data in the session. The session of a user is the same for the whole webapp. And GAE makes the session persistent, so another JVM will see the session created by the first one. The remember-me cookie is just another way to authenticate a user.

Comment: For the record: If sessions are persistent throughout JVM's, then the best solution might be to keep track of the sessions and put a Cookie the first time (and eventually update it) so when the user close the browser he doesn't have to authenticate again. Thanks!

Comment: Err, that's precisely what I tell you to do in my answer. The cookie is used to automatically authenticate the user which sends the cookie, without the need to provide credentials. And once automatically authenticated thanks to the cookie, the identity of the user can be stored in the session.